# I am getting stuck on how to connect react js to phpmyadmin databases . Can you please explain me that properly . I am a beginner in react

Tags: reactjs

Hey every one I am a child start learning react js . But I am having trouble about how to connect react js to phpmyadmin databases . Please help me I havenot import / installed any api modules . Explain me from start to end

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to connect your react app with phpmyadmin . phpmyadmin is only provide database ui .
instead you have to make your backend same as it is you have created your frontend with react . you can use Node.js for your backend if you want to
your backend in Javascript .and your backend will connect to your database which you can show in phpmyadmin .